# Remake JS and jQuery into AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have one question about JS and AngularJS. I have written an application in JS and JQ and I'm wondering how difficult it would be to remake it in AngularJS. I am asking because I've never worked with Angular.

Comment: Ok thans delete question

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to start with some tutorials ([codescool](https://www.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js) offer the best one in my opinion)

Then google is my encyclopedia about single cases. If you post some case probably we can help  you but your question is too general to have an answer

Comment: This should be a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @JordanS The question shouldn't have been posted in the first place so why nitpick on this dude about it needing to be a comment and not an answer?

Comment: @zerohero can we not all learn something?

Answer (score 1):

Angular1 is noting but organised JS, where you have controllers and related views and it can be totally written in the plain JS, you would however need to understand angular format of writing controllers.

Angular2 on the other hand should be written using typescript

Answer (score 1):

Starts with some basic AngularJS tutorials like [AngularJS Guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide), get ramp-up on it and then starts desinging app in Architectural way in terms of Angular (MVC).

AngularJs provides MVC paltform where you can separate your Model, Views and Controller, so all your js related code goes in controller(Business logic) and model will be used in Views for data binding.